# Em dash or colon in formal writing

Tags: formality, dashes, colons

In formal writing, should I use an **em dash**

> The Earth consists of three layers — crust, mantle, and core.

or a **colon**

> The Earth consists of three layers: crust, mantle, and core.

?

Comment: @tchrist What did you mean by "don't forget the comma"?

Comment: You only have one comma for three things. You should have two of them.

Comment: @tchrist Yes, I know because I put "and" word before the last word. Is that also informal? :)

Comment: You should still use the comma.  The *and* is no replacement.

Comment: @tchrist So correct is "crust, mantle, and core"? I am from Slovakia and we do not use comma before "and", therefore I am asking.

Comment: @tchrist Comma added.

Comment: Please note that what tchrist is telling you here about using a comma before *and* is only his opinion. There are many discussions on here about this issue and many who do not agree with him. So do not take it as a rule that you must use a comma before *and*.

Comment: @tchrist Why "Don't use an em-dash"? I don't currently have a strong view either way and am interested in your reasoning.

Comment: Please, when someone downvote this question, write here the reason of it. I think my question is relevant and clear.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As @tchrist said, I would recommend the colon: "The Earth consists of three layers: crust, mantle and core." However, the comma before the conjunction in the list is optional, as I understand; see http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Serial_comma.

From some quick research, it seems that the colon generally introduces a continuation of the thought or a list of items: more information that the writer is including. The em-dash, on the other hand, signals a change in topic (a parenthesis) or a summary of the preceding thought—a sudden movement of thought which should not be read as a continuation of the first part of the sentence.

As an example, here is a sentence from Charles Dickens' *Great Expectations* which uses both the colon and the em-dash:

> He was gobbling mincemeat, meatbone, bread, cheese, and pork pie, all
>   at once: staring distrustfully while he did so at the mist all round
>   us, and often stopping—even stopping his jaws—to listen.

Notice how the sentence thought continues after the colon, while the em-dash sets apart a thought that can be omitted without damage to the original idea of the sentence: "staring distrustfully...and often stopping...to listen."